How to create a function in R to add emmeans-contrasts output to a ggplot-graphic?
I hope someone can help me with this problem. I have no background in computer science or programing, which makes it hard to understand why my code doesn't work.
My goal is to create a number of plots, like the one below. To test for differences between means I'am using a mixed linear model (lme4::lmer + lmerTest for p-values) together with pairwise comparisons using the emmeans-package.
enter image description here
In another post on stack overflow (answered by learners) I found a method to extract the contrasts-output and how to add them to a boxplot using the ggpubr-package. I works fine to do a plot with significance levels manually. However, the code is quite verbose so I would prefer to create a function in order to reduce the risk for errors when creating multiple plots using different variables and situations/conditions.
Below is an erroneous code, but it illustrates what I try to accomplish. I have understood, that it can be complicated to introduce a formula inside a function, and the formula arguments may needs to be transferred to a character and then reused with as.formula, but I have not been able to do this. Creating the plot with a function works fine, but not formulating the mixed model and extracting/adding the significance levels.
library(tidyverse)
library(lmerTest)
library(lme4)
library(reshape) # using melt()
library(ggpubr) # using stat_pvalue_manual()

plot_signf <- function(df, condition, var){
  
  model <- df %>% 
    filter(prov == {{condition}}) %>% 
    lmer(log(var) ~ part + (1|subject), data = .)
  
  summary(model)
  plot(model)
  
  signif <- emmeans(model, specs = pairwise ~ part, type = "response")
  
  #Extracting emmeans-contrats output
  p.val.test <- pwpm(signif, means = FALSE, flip = TRUE,reverse = TRUE)
  p.val.test <- sub("[<>]", "", p.val.test)
  p.matx <- matrix(as.numeric((p.val.test)),nrow = length(p.val.test[,1]),ncol = length(p.val.test[,1]))
  rownames(p.matx) <- colnames(p.matx) <- colnames(p.val.test)
  p.matx[upper.tri(p.matx, diag=FALSE)] <- NA
  stat.test <- subset(melt(p.matx),!is.na(value))
  #ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual() needs data organized in group 1-2 + p-value. 
  names(stat.test) <- c("group1","group2","p.adj")
  stat.test[stat.test$p.adj<=0.001,"p.adj.signif"] <- "***"
  stat.test[stat.test$p.adj>0.001 & stat.test$p.adj<=0.01,"p.adj.signif"] <- "**"
  stat.test[stat.test$p.adj>0.01 & stat.test$p.adj<=0.05,"p.adj.signif"] <- "*"
  stat.test[ stat.test$p.adj>0.05,"p.adj.signif"] <- "ns"
  
  df %>% 
    filter(prov == {{condition}}) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = part, y = {{var}}))+
    geom_boxplot(staplewidth = 0.3, outliers = FALSE)+
    geom_jitter(aes(color = part), alpha = 0.6, width = 0.2)+
    stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test,
                       y.position = max(df$var[df$prov == {condition}], na.rm=TRUE),
                       step.increase = 0.1)+
    theme_pubr()+
    theme(legend.position = "element_blank")
  
}

plot_signf(df = mean, condition = "snp", var = IR_AUC)

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Your question is very unclear. You say you want to use emmeans, but the lengthy code example doesn't even involve that package. Also, the emmeans package provides quite a few ways of graphing its results. So why not use those rather than trying to reinvent them from scratch?
